# User defined function in ms excel 2010 for fetching environ variable user name does not work

Tags: excel, protected, udf, vba

I created a user defined function in ms excel 2010 for fetching current logged in user thru environvariable "USERNAME".

However, on some machines running ms excel2010 on win7, this function does not update current user name.

I had packaged it in a protected worksheet and distributed to several users.

The udf code goes this way :
Public Function UserName()
    UserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function

Then  the function is called using the formula:

=Username()

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the code of the `Function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function WhoAmI() As String
   Application.Volatile
   WhoAmI = "The NT Logon User is " & Environ("username")
   WhoAmI = WhoAmI & vbCrLf & "The Office Username is " & Application.UserName
End Function
```

Should work on any *Windows* system.

Comment: I do not need application user name. I need only windows username. So can I skip the application.username part. Also, what does application.volatile do.

Comment: @user3305648  You can omit the part that you do not need......the `Application.Volatile` forces re-calculation when a different user opens the workbook.

Comment: Thanks. As I understand, application.recalculate will work only if any cell in a workbook changes. So will it update when a different user opens the workbook.